# php foreach doesn't loop properly

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, associative-array

when i execute this code:

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query) ) {
    echo '<br>while';
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        echo ' foreach';
    }
}
```

i get the right output:
eg:

```
while foreach foreach foreach foreach foreach foreach foreach
while foreach foreach foreach foreach foreach foreach foreach
```

but when i change the

```
echo ' foreach';
```

with

```
echo $value;
```

i don't get any results printed.
i've already checked similar question but nothing worked for me.

query:

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $options);
    if($conn === false) die("<pre>".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        //tabella selezionata
        echo $_REQUEST['tab'];
        //tabella
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$_REQUEST['tab']."";
        $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
        if ($query === false){
            exit("<pre>".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
```

Comment: Maybe each of your `$value`s is a `bool(false)` or an empty `string`.  What happens with `var_dump($value)`?

Comment: Try `var_dump($row)` before the loop, or `echo " $key -> $value ";` inside the loop, and see if it gives you anything.

Comment: this is result set of your query not an array, please just try to print $row and you get it what happen..

Comment: use print_r($row) check the result and change the code accordingly

Comment: Nonsense... Of course you can use a `foreach` inside a `while`. Hell, you can even use a `for`i n a `foreach` in a `while`in a `switch...case` in another `foreach` if it pleases you.

Comment: @roberto06 you're right, var_dump($value) it prints out line of NULL, but i didnt understand why, i'll post the rest of the code.

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$_REQUEST['tab']."";` is EXTREMELY DANGEROUS!  Don't ever do this in a web-facing system!  https://xkcd.com/327/  You should use prepared statements and input validation (yes, both) to prevent SQL injection attacks.  PHP provides support via sqlsrv_prepare() http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php

Comment: @GordonM i know it's a bad idea but that's not going to face the web, anyway could it cause the query to return an array of NULL?

Comment: Yes it could, if the contents of $_REQUEST is malformed (By the way, the use of $_REQUEST is also very risky as it means you don't know where input is coming from).  Aside from protecting against malicious input proper input validation and prepared statements will also protect against input errors